# CVE Patching assistance

Tags: security

Version - 22.04.2 LTS

I am new to the Linux and was hoping to get some assistance regarding CVE patching.I can see plenty of CVE's which I need to address but I am not sure how to patch it.

I know the following commands are meant to scan for updated packages but from what I can see there are still newer versions?

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Example is: CVE-2022-40284 (I can see a patches link which links me to Github?)

Not too sure where to go on this one and would really appreciate any assistance.

Thanks ALL!

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu, *normally* major things in major packages get patched by the SEcurity Team (see [the CVE you're asking about here](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-40284)), and then a standard `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` will pull in patched software from the repositories.  The CVE in question though is already patched

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if a CVE has been fixed in Ubuntu's repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563408/how-can-i-tell-if-a-cve-has-been-fixed-in-ubuntus-repositories). A step-by-step example of one CVE is at https://askubuntu.com/a/1438590/19626 .