OpenSSH version upgrade to 9.8
The versions of OpenSSH up to 4.4p1, plus versions from 8.5p1 to 9.7p1 running on glibc-Linux, are vulnerable. The latest version on Openssh was released on July 1, 2024. So when will the latest version of OpenSSH be available in Ubuntu versions 20.04, and 22.04?
Please make this as soon as possible, because the compile installation has some security issues. So it will be good if Ubuntu officially releases the latest version.
https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html

Please note that the users of this site are just volunteers using Ubuntu. We are not the Ubuntu team. We don't have any power to change ubuntu policies. Great question, though

In the future, if you want to report a bug, please use Launchpad instead https://bugs.launchpad.net/

@ArchismanPanigrahi we already have tags for [tag:security] and [tag:vulnerability] (which in itself is pretty useless), we don't need a tag for [tag:cve] on top of those.

This question is similar to: Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  Security fixes are backported to released products, not the newer versions of applications, as per stable release policies...  Its rare for backporting a new version to be done, instead of fixes themselves

There is a specific CVE mitigation walk-through at https://askubuntu.com/a/1438590/19626 that many folks find helpful for questions like this.

In future, before asking similar questions, check out Ubuntu CVE Reports. Chances are, the patch is already applied to the appropriate package in Ubuntu.


The versions of OpenSSH up to 4.4p1, plus versions from 8.5p1 to 9.7p1 running on glibc-Linux, are vulnerable.

Ubuntu developers already backported the patch in the older version of openssh to stop the vulnerability.
Update Ubuntu with the following commands to get this security update (if you already haven't).
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade


The latest version on Openssh was released on July 1, 2024. So when will the latest version of OpenSSH be available in Ubuntu versions 20.04, and 22.04?

It will not happen. Ubuntu does not update the version of the software (unless it is a browser/email client). Instead, the developers backport the appropriate security patches into the older version of software available in Ubuntu. Please read Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software? to know why.

Please make this as soon as possible, because the compile installation has some security issues.

No, Ubuntu has already backported the patch to fix the vulnerability.
